# Simplify the following expression using Boolean identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

The question is to simplify the following expression:

$$(xz + y'x)' + y(x + y)(z' + y)$$

Rewritten using discrete mathematics symbols:
$$ \neg((x \wedge z) \vee (\neg y \wedge x)) \vee y \wedge (x \vee y)(\neg z \vee y)$$

Whenever I attempt to solve it, I end up with y+x' or ($y\vee\neg x$). I'm not sure if this is the correct result as it omits the z variable.

I believe I'm making a mistake somewhere following this last expression:

$$\begin{align}
(xz+y'x)'+y(x+y)(z'+y) &= (x'+z')(y+x')+(xy+yy)(z'+y) \nonumber \\
&= (x'y+x'x'+z'y+z'x')+(xy+y)(z'+y) \nonumber \\
&= x'y+x'+z'y+z'x'+xyz'+xyy+yz'+yy \nonumber \\
&= x'y+x'+z'y+z'x'+xyz'+xy+yz'+y \nonumber \\
\end{align}$$
The problem is that I'm unsure in which order to eliminate the variables (think x'y + x' = x'(y + 1) = x'(1) = x').
I'm only looking for a nudge in this instance on how best to proceed.

Comment: $y+x'$ is correct. When you multiply out $y(x+y)(z'+y)$, you find that one term is $y$, and since each of the other terms contains a factor of $y$, the $y$ term absorbs the others. The first term ultimately reduces to $x'y+x'+yz'+x'z'$, in which the $x'$ term absorbs all of the others except the $yz'$ term, which is absorbed in the $y$ from the second term of the original expression.

Comment: Oh? So in that case, does this mean whichever truth value is z is irrelevant in this expression?

Comment: Yes, it does. $ $

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating Brian M. Scott's response (marking this post as answered), y + x' is indeed the correct simplified Boolean expression. The omission of z means that whatever truth value z takes on is irrelevant when considering the truth value of the entire expression.